# Error during passing data between fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Im trying to pass data between two fragments but i have an error with arguments in execution when i launch fullFragment
i updated my code
Can you help me ?

architecture :
[image: Fragments architecture]

ListeFragment (sender) :

```
class ListeFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance(s: String) = ListeFragment()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_fragment, container, false)
    val photo1 = layout.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageButton1)

    val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListeViewModel::class.java)

        imageButton1.setOnClickListener {
            val newFragment = FullFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("key1", "data")
            newFragment.arguments = args
          Navigation.findNavController(imageButton1).navigate(R.id.versFullFragment);
        }
```

FullFragment (receiver):

```
class FullFragment : Fragment() {
companion object {
    fun newInstance() = FullFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: FullViewModel

override fun onCreate( savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    var value1 = getArguments()?.getString("key1")
    Log.v("value" , value1.toString())
    Toast.makeText(context, value1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.full_fragment, container, false)
    return layout
}
```

Comment: Hello. As we can see there is a difference in the shared code and logs. You're creating `ListeFragment` but in logs we're getting error for `FullFragment `. Could you recheck navigation part? If it's not a navigation problem please add more details to post.

Comment: i updated my code no crash but value1 is null

Comment: first in your ListFragment you get the imagebutton in a var photo1 . use photo1 instead of imagebutton itself . and sec in your FullFragment try declare your getArgument in the oncreateView not in the on Create . I hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "newFragment.arguments = args" do because in FullFragment class I don't see any variable with that name, however you have to use "Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)" to set Fragment Arguments from the first one. Then in the Full you will have a correct result from "FullFragment.getArguments()" method.

PS: don't forget that the Context could be NULL in Fragment class and it should be handled in proper way.